Unable to catch/export some cookies
In attempt to automation of some job on a certain site, I use php-webdriver. Target website is written in Vue. For certain POST query this site uses cookies, but this cookies does not present nor in Web Developer Tool > Storage > Cookie, nor in dump via $driver->manage()->getCookies(). I can see this cookies only in certain POST queries.
Also, I have used Tampermonkey for logging (set|get)cookies events but w/o luck... I was thinking of using Tampermonkey for catching and saving this cookies.
I have not seen this "hidden" cookies ever.
So, need advise how to catch this cookies.

Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? I blogged about troubleshooting cookie problems here https://nestenius.se/net/debugging-cookie-problems/   perhaps can give you some ideas.

Please, add relevant info, it's unknown what the case is. "I can see this cookies only in certain POST queries" - but other users didn't. This could be httponly cookies or something else

This Vue App sends some HTTPS POST requests for certain purposes, such as changing the rate if the item. This POST contain 2 cookies, which is not present in any of type of storage in the browser. This Vue App not mine and I do not has access to codes and so on.

This vague question will not help anyone understand what you are facing. You may be facing a completely different problem than you think. If the cookie is not in the cookie jar, then its value is generated elsewhere. It would be best if you searched for that. Usually in JS script. or inside the form that you are submitting. Give us a proper scenario. like the post API form DOM and the name of that certain site.

@SA,
I know what is the problem, but i do not know how to say more clearly :). Yes, I know, cookies are generated inside JS of the web-application. This is some protection was introduced by author of this web site, because a lot of scripts for automation some jobs was working before. My investigation of the JS-code without luck as for now.
This web site is not public.
